# How to skip battle animations in Civilization V?

Tags: civilization-5

I know in strategic mode there are no battle animations. But how can I skip them in 3D mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oak's right, there's a setting to turn them off for an entire match. In case you want to do that:

Set Up Game > Advanced Setup > Quick Combat

As pretty as the animations are, they slow the game too much for me so I always play with them off.

Though now that I know Oak's F10 trick (+1, nice tip) maybe I'll consider enabling the prettiness for some matches. :-)

Comment: After much experience playing CIV and after using Oak's F10 trick for many games. I like it better to remember to set Quick Combat in advanced options.

Answer (score 15):

Since version 1.0.1.674, you can enable and disable Quick Combat and Quick Movement in the options menu. **Quick Combat** will do what you want.

[image]

Alternatively, if you want just to skip the occasional animation but let the rest appear, you can just click <kbd>F10</kbd> twice in quick succession. It's a bit silly but it works, especially useful when aircraft are involved.

Comment: Wow, that is incredibly useful. Nowadays I always enable quick combat, but when you forget there seems to be no way to turn it on later (although perhaps you could edit a save). Winning a way by stealth bombing the enemy to smithereens doesn't need to take hours with this trick.

Comment: Soltuion for faster plance animations: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=83056827

Comment: This also works in Multiplayer games if you are the host.

Answer (score 3):

You can also change the Quick Combat option during the game. You have to use FireTuner to do that (it is a runtime Lua console available in Civilization V SDK).
Although doing so is not recommended, I didn't experience any problems so far.

Follow [this link](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=401194) if you are interested.