# How to disable attack animations for Civ 5?

Tags: civilization-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to skip battle animations in Civilization V?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25670/how-to-skip-battle-animations-in-civilization-v)

Watching animations like planes attacking a city takes about 20secs, which is very painful to have to watch over and over again, is there someway to disable the animations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sometimes watch animations, you can leave them enabled and part that you can speed up play in "strategic" view (iconic hexes). press F10 to switch it on and off.

You can even order attack and press F10 to resolve that one attack without fight animation (only movement "animation", and simple one)

Answer (score 7):

You have to choose the Quick Combat option from the advanced game setup menu...before you start the game. There doesn't appear to be any way to enable this option once the game has started.