# How can I turn on Battle animations when playing online in Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5

I have seen other [questions on here about disabling battle animations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25670/how-to-skip-battle-animations-in-civilization-v), but I would like them shown when I play online with friends.  Is this possible to turn them on?  If so, how?

If my troops get owned, I would like to know where and how.  Animations usually help me with this [as I am relatively new to the game].

Comment: I don't think its possible to have them on for multi-player games, its part of trying to speed the game up for everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to enable battle animations in online play. You need to look out for a mod.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the quick action option once you've started your online game and this will enable your animations. Basically, "quick action" = no animations.